# Direct way for firing up some events when a boolean field changes?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, boolean

I wonder if there is a way to directly control some events when a boolean field is changing from true to false?

something like using delegate?

Actually I have lots of user input controls (check box, text box and etc..) and I am looking for a way around the using of foreach and control.disabled stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are always good to fire up event from within:

```
private bool check = false;
public bool MyCheckboxChecked
{
    get
    {
        return check;
    }

    set
    {
        if (check == true && value == false)
            MyEvent("MyCheckboxChecked is about to change from true to false!");
        check = value;
    }
}
```

If you want to monitor public fields of controls (ie `CheckBox.Checked`), you can always hookup for events already provided by them like `CheckedChanged`.

Comment: I believe you must place the Rising statement after the value changing statemtent ..

Comment: True, it would be better to raise ValueChanging event before actual value change and ValueChanged event after the assignment just like framework itself does. Fixed the typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a property to set the field value. Raise a PropertyChanged event in the setter of the property.

Sample code:

```
bool Flag
{
    get { return this.flag; }
    set
    {
        if (this.flag != value) 
        {
            this.flag = value;
            // Raise PropertyChanged event here ..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's right. If you are using WPF, you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and Binding which is very convenient for you need.

Or use action:

```
private bool isIt;
public Action YourAction{get; set;}

public bool IsIt
{
get{return isIt;}
set{isIt = value; if(YourAction != null) YourAction();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, use an event raiser on the set accessor of a property instead of changing directly the member variable...